# Switch display output without rebooting but not in Xorg

Tags: linux, video, console, nvidia

My graphic card has two output (VGA and DVI). Is it possible to switch from one to the other without rebooting ?

It works in Xorg by restarting the X server (I guess it should be doable with `xrandr` too) but I'd like to do it in the **linux console**.

I have looked at [vbetool](http://www.codon.org.uk/~mjg59/vbetool/) but I am not sure it is the right way (the commands I tried did not work anyway).

I have a nvidia card.

Comment: Does `xrandr` not count as the Linux console?

Comment: `xrandr` would probably allow me to switch the display of Xorg from the console. What I would like to do is switch the output for the console itself (on `tty1-6`)

Answer (score 2):

I can't try it right know, but I found this answer to your question:
`fbgetty /dev/tty8 /dev/fb0`
`fbgetty /dev/tty9 /dev/fb1`

Where:
- /dev/tty8/9/n are the terminals you want to move
- /dev/fb0/1/v are the framebuffer devices you want to use ... it should switch between your outputs

Solution is taken from this forum thread: http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/debian-linux/96430-move-tty-second-monitor.html